# Building Select Query Using IN(...) Clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, jdbc

I need to do select * based on a list of input ids, what's the best way of batch select?  here's what I have

```
StringBuilder inClause = new StringBuilder();
boolean firstValue = true;
for (int i=0; i < batchSize; i++) {
  inClause.append('?');
  if ( firstValue ) {
    firstValue = false;
  } else {
    inClause.append(',');
  }
}
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select id, name from users where id in (" + inClause.toString() + ')');


for (int i=0; i < batchSize; i++) {
  stmt.setInt(i);  // or whatever values you are trying to query by
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks pretty fine to me. Just spotted a logical bug there in this block of code,

```
boolean firstValue = true;
for (int i=0; i < batchSize; i++) {
  inClause.append('?');
  if ( firstValue ) {
    firstValue = false;
  } else {
    inClause.append(',');
  }
}
```

It will not append a `,` after the first element. And there would be a `,` after the last. So, you need not care about that `,` here. Just do it this way

```
for (int i=0; i < batchSize; i++) {
  inClause.append('?, ');
}
```

Then chop last two characters like this,

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select id, name from users where id in (" + 
    inClause.substring(0, inClause.length()-2) + ')');
```

Comment: is this the fastest way possible?

Comment: @user775187: If the `id` is unique, and you need to query records based on several `ids` -- provided there is no other option, then `IN(...)` is the way. Hence, you have to build your query using this or similar technique.